# How to parse complex xml

Tags: android, xml

Hi all please let me know how to parse the following xml string. I have tried many methods but no response please give me some ideas asap.

thanks

```
String responce ="
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <soapenv:Body>
      <ns1:loginVerificationResponse soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="ecgw">
       <loginVerificationReturn xsi:type="ns2:Map" xmlns:ns2="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap">
        <item xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <key xsi:type="soapenc:string">CLIENTID</key>
         <value xsi:type="soapenc:integer">569604</value>
        </item>
        <item>
         <key xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">AUTHORISED</key>
         <value xsi:type="soapenc:string" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">TRUE</value>
        </item>
       </loginVerificationReturn>
      </ns1:loginVerificationResponse>
     </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `XmlPullParser`. See the [doc here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html). There is more Example code in the documentation.

```
String responce = "your xml content here";
XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
xpp.setInput(new StringReader(responce));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ksoap2 for Android](https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/) to parse SOAP responses. Generally speaking, SOAP is a pain in the *** on Android.

For general XML parsing I would recommend [SimpleXML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) to map XML to Java classes/ objects.